# getX() & getY() MotionListener

Tags: java, awt

Im searching to get coordinates x/y from my chessboard who contain cases ! 
I use actually System.out.println to get that but it's not the good method... 
I need to get these data from a method getX() and getY() !

Column: A-H
Row: 1-8

Im searching since 3 hours.....

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class CoordBoutons extends JFrame {

        CoordBoutons() {
            super("GridLayout");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Container contenant = getContentPane();
            contenant.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    contenant.add(new CaseEchiquier(i, j));
                }
            }

            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }

        class CaseEchiquier extends JPanel {

            private int lin, col;

            CaseEchiquier(int i, int j) {
                lin = i;
                col = j;
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 75));
                setBackground((i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.GRAY);
                addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                  /*  private Color background;

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        background = getBackground();
                        setBackground(Color.RED);
                        repaint();

                    }
                  */

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                         System.out.println((char)('a' + col) + "" + (8 - lin));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

                    }

                 /*   @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        setBackground(background);
                    }
                 */   

                });
    //            addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    //                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    //                    System.out.println((char) ('a' + col) + "" + (8 - lin));
    //
    //                }
    //            });
            }


        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                CoordBoutons coordBoutons = new CoordBoutons();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not understandable, please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) have the `getX` and `getY` methods that you can use to get the coordinates. use it as below:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   int x = e.getX(); 
}
```

`x` will in this case contain the coordinates to where the user pressed the mouse button.

UPDATE:
I've updated the code a bit with regard to your comment. Here we use `getSource()` that we cast to a `CaseEchiquier` since that is what type of object that getSource will return. After that, you have the object that the user pressed and you can perform whatever logic that you want to do with it

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    CaseEchiquier current =(CaseEchiquier)e.getSource(); // get the object that the user pressed
    int lin = current.getLin();
    int col= current.getCol();
    //do something else with the object current
}
```

Also you need to add a `getLin` and `getCol` method to your CaseEchiquier class

Comment: Yes but I need to get coords like that :  COL: A-H   and ROW:   1-8      not by having 0.37 or 0.02 etc....  Thank you anyway.

Comment: Updated the code with regard to your comment

Comment: Oh thank you so much ! I understand the trick now =) I had suceed by another mean who was most long.. Thank you for this shortcut ;)